# "driver contact details" vs. "driver's contact details"

Tags: possessives, attributives

1. You’ll receive your **driver contact** details.
2. You’ll receive your **driver's contact** details.

Can you tell me please which of these sentences is correct? Is *'s* necessary or not in this context?

Comment: Can you clarify whether or not you are the driver in question? #1 *could* make sense (maybe) if it described a packet of info that you would need in order to fulfill the role of a driver.  Speaking of another person (who drives) you'd want #2,  Without clarification, it's hard to say.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I meant if I have a chauffeured car rental company for example and I want to say my customer that our company send him driver contact details for additional safety.

Answer (score 0):

Either is correct. There is a subtle difference in that 1. refers to the generic - it feels like you have a pile of packs of these details and you'll be sending the reader one from your pile. Whereas 2. feels more like the reader is holding his own, singular, driver's pack - and is looking at it.

But really it is such a subtle difference and both are correct, in my view.

1 is more generic, 2 is a bit more personal.

Use 2, if you want involvement in your reader 'yay! you got your pack! - now what are you gonna do with it?!' Use 1. if you want to be more generic, dry and less personal 'we, the government, are organising everything and sending out packs...'

But nobody will feel you are wrong, whichever you use.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I meant if I have a chauffeured car rental company for example and I want to say my customer that our company send him driver contact details for additional safety.